# Why in some Dribble UI's User Avatar (user settings) are kept in bottom left?

Tags: usability, gui-design, user-expectation, user-centered-design

Just curious, I saw in some of the dribble shots are designed with the User Avatar in the bottom left of the screens and also noticed on BitBucket UI.

[image: reference from: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/remote-Too-many-invalid-password-attempts-Log-in-at-https-id/qaq-p/1108614]

**Is there any usability factor for keeping it at Bottom Left?**

Answer (score 4):

I think the main reason is to leave free space to work with the application.

An extreme example is [discord](https://discord.com/).

On the home screen, the lower left position for the avatar looks like a random decision:

[image]

But when starting to work on the application, the position of the avatar, an element that is not used as often except to define basic work preferences, makes more sense, since it leaves room for all the other working components more complex and frequently used:

[image]

Perceptually the **isolated** user avatar in the lower left corner allows it to be viewed easily for access if necessary.

In applications with screen changes, each menu component, tools, panels, etc., tends to vary in position according to the number of items, as happens in *discord*. The lower left location can be set as a **fixed position** and is the one with the least impact in terms of clicks on the screen, which relegates its importance to the last level.

If I had to highlight main reasons:

- Clear differentiation between working and personal area
- Less frequented corner
- Fixed position
- Isolation
- Ease and immediacy access